# What should I do about a hole in my dryer hose?

Tags: dryer, exhaust-vent

My cats tore a hole in our electric dryer vent hose, and I used the dryer to dry-clean a sweater using one of those sheets that you put in the dryer.
Now I'm really worried about the fumes in the house and how it will affect us.
I dried a couple of loads of clothes. I'm trying not to freak out!

Comment: The fumes from an electric dryer are not toxic. It is just warm air, and lint that is coming out. If it was a gas dryer, then I would be concerned. It definitely must be replaced regardless though.

Comment: My husband said the opening into the wall is not round , its oval , so can we still find a metal dryer vent to fit it at stores like Lowes / Home Depot ? We need to fix it asap so I can do these mountains of laundry and I don't want to worry about fire hazards ! Thanks so much for all your help .

Answer (score 2):

If your cats tore a hole in it, it has to be flex hose.

Do yourself a huge favor and replace every inch of flex hose with solid metal dryer vent. Flex hose collects vast amounts of lint that get past the lint filer and is impossible to clean effectively (not to mention being delicate enough to be torn by cats.)

As a one-time event I would not be overly concerned about the dry-cleaning sheet. But I would definitely scrap the hose and replace it with solid metal before using the dryer again.

Comment: How do you line up the dryer to connect to the dryer vent in the wall with solid metal dryer hose? I have always used flexible dryer hose and it never got plugged with lint. Our present washer and dryer are only 3 years old and two retired people in their 70s don't do a lot of laundry so I'm sure it is free, but still if there is a better alternative, I'm open to it.

Comment: The elbows for solid metal can be adjusted by rotating the individual sections around. It's not very hard to make them line up, though it can be a bit tricky to figure out how they interact the first time.

Comment: I gotta go with jim on this one I use flex to be able to pull the dryer, I usually blow my hard pipe once a year and at that time I shake out the flex, even prior to doing this I never had an issue .with the short piece of flex.